# How can I properly transform the 'this' keyword in a typescript-transformer function?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, ts-loader

I created a typescript transformer that traverses the AST and changes array calls from

`myArr.push(el)` to `Array.prototype.push.call(myArr, args)`

This works well for all cases apart the case where the array is using the `this` key word inside a class:

`this.myArr.push(el)` transforms to `Array.prototype.push.call(this.myArr, args)`
while the correct transformation should be:
`this.myArr.push(el)` to `Array.prototype.push.call(_this.myArr, args)`
(the `_this` having been already created by the ts-loader plugin)

How can I achieve this?

This is the code of my transformer:

```
function getType(type) {
  if (type && type.symbol && type.symbol.name) {
    return type.symbol.name;
  } else if (
    type &&
    type.literalType &&
    type.literalType.symbol &&
    type.literalType.symbol.name
  ) {
    return type.literalType.symbol.name;
  }
  return null;
}
exports.__esModule = true;
const { ClassificationTypeNames } = require("typescript");
var ts = require("typescript");
var transformer = function (typechecker) {
  return function (context) {
    var visitor = function (node) {
      // 1. First check: chained expression
      // if it's array.filter().join().map() then I want to change only the first part
      // meaning 
      // if property access is a call expression - ignore and dont change
      if (
        ts.isCallExpression(node) &&
        ts.isPropertyAccessExpression(node.expression) &&
        ts.isCallExpression(node.expression.expression)

      ) {
        return ts.visitEachChild(node, visitor, context);
        
      }

      if (
        ts.isCallExpression(node) &&
        ts.isPropertyAccessExpression(node.expression)
      ) {
        const type = typechecker.getTypeAtLocation(node.expression.expression);
        const typeNameS = getType(type); 
        if (typeNameS === "Array") {
          const methodName = node.expression.name.getText();
          const callArgs = node.arguments;
          const identifier = node.expression.expression.getText();
          return ts.createCall(
            ts.createPropertyAccess(
              ts.createPropertyAccess(
                ts.createPropertyAccess(
                  ts.createIdentifier("Array"),
                  ts.createIdentifier("prototype")
                ),
                ts.createIdentifier(methodName)
              ),
              ts.createIdentifier("call")
            ),
            undefined,
            [ts.createIdentifier(identifier), ...callArgs]
          );
        }
      }

      return ts.visitEachChild(node, visitor, context);
    };
    return function (node) {
      return ts.visitNode(node, visitor);
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: If you are transforming after `this` may have been translated to `_this`, you will run into other errors. For example, destructuring creates aliases.

Comment: I am transforming on the 'before' call in ts-loader. Is that okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error.

I was getting the identifier and creating it manually.

```
const identifier = node.expression.expression.getText();
```

and then

```
ts.createIdentifier(identifier)
```

The correct way to construct the new node is to pass `node.expression.expression` directly to the construction call.

```
 return ts.createCall(
        ts.createPropertyAccess(
          ts.createPropertyAccess(
            ts.createPropertyAccess(
              ts.createIdentifier("Array"),
              ts.createIdentifier("prototype")
            ),
            ts.createIdentifier(methodName)
          ),
          ts.createIdentifier("call")
        ),
        undefined,
        [node.expression.expression, ...callArgs]
      );
```

and that way the typescript engine knows how to build the `_this` and `this` references correctly.